# How to toggle data attribute value according to checkbox states?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to set `data-active` attribute of `<li>` element to `Y` "Yes", or `N` "No" according to the active checkbox states either checked or unchecked respectively.

My sample code is like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change','#active',function(){
    li = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).attr('checked')=='true') {
      $(this).attr('checked','false');
      li.attr('data-active','N');
    } else {
      li.attr('data-active','Y');
      $(this).attr('checked','true');
    }
    console.log(li.data('active'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol class="example">
  <li data-active="N">Option2 (Active <input id="active" type="checkbox">)</li>
</ol>
```

From my code above, the event handler on `#active` matched only in `else` clause, regardless to whatever the checkbox state is.

Understanding that there are plenty of similar questions to mine, however I tried them but none solves my problem.

How can I do to toggle `data-active` to "yes" or "no" according to checkbox state? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.data` and `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change','#active',function(){
        li = $(this).parent();
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            li.data('active','Y');
        } else {
            li.data('active','N');
        }
        console.log(li.data('active'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="example">
    <li data-active="N">Option2 (Active <input id="active" type="checkbox">)</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Checkbox state toggle the value 'N','Y' very well. But I noticed `li.data('active','Y');` won't change data-active value of `li` element according to checked states. In stead, it work if I used `li.attr('data-active','Y');` :)

Comment: From what I know, that's because `.data` will get only the initial data from `data-*` attribute however it can't be used to set `data-*` attribute   

(**EDIT:** Think of `.data` like setting a properties of the DOM element without modifying DOM properties)